# Using mongodb aggregate to match documents and get all values for a field

Tags: mongodb

In Mongo 3.4

I have a collection with documents in the format:

Type1:

```
{
"Level1": {
    "@version": "genR",
    "@revision": "aux",
    "Level2": {
        "container": {
            "type": "ARRAY",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "Type": "STRING",
                            "Value": "Currency"
                        },
                        {
                            "Type": "STRING",
                            "Value": "EUR"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "Type": "STRING",
                            "Value": "Portfolio"
                        },
                        {
                            "Type": "STRING",
                            "Value": "ABCDEF"
                        }
                    ]
                },
             ]
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Type 2:

```
 {
"Level1": {
    "@version": "genR",
    "@revision": "aux",
    "Level2": {
        "container": {
            "type": "ARRAY",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "Type": "STRING",
                            "Value": "Currency"
                        },
                        {
                            "Type": "STRING",
                            "Value": "EUR"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "Type": "STRING",
                            "Value": "Portfolio"
                        },
                        {
                            "Type": "STRING",
                            "Value": "ABCDEF"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "Type": "STRING",
                            "Value": "Short Description"
                        },
                        {
                            "Type": "STRING",
                            "Value": "Cash Only"
                        }
                    ]
                },
             ]
          }
      }
  }
}
```

How do i write an aggregate statement so that I get ALL the Currency Values, ONLY from the documents where Portfolio matches a certain value.

I have been using pymongo's aggregate framework as below:

```
pipeline = [{"$unwind":"$Level1.Level2.container.categories"},{"$unwind":"$Level1.Level2.container.categories.category"},{"$match":{"Level1.Level2.container.categories.category.Value":"Portfolio"}}]
pprint(db.command('aggregate',collection,pipeline=pipeline))
```

But no results. Pymongo is a little confusing. Even if someone can point the general approach, it would really help.

The expected response assuming 4 matching documents (each with varying number of category items) is:

```
{'Currency': [{'Level1': {'Level2': {'container': {'categories': {'category': {'Value': 'EUR'}}}}}},
          {'Level1': {'Level2': {'container': {'categories': {'category': {'Value': 'EUR'}}}}}},
          {'Level1': {'Level2': {'container': {'categories': {'category': {'Value': 'USD'}}}}}},
          {'Level1': {'Level2': {'container': {'categories': {'category': {'Value': 'EUR'}}}}}}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure is not ideal but you can use below query.

The below `$match` stage `$and`s two conditions. Looks in `category` array (`$elemMatch`) under `categories` (`$elemMatch`) array for elements satisfying both (`$all`) `Portfolio` match with `ABCDEF` value condition followed by condition for element with `Currrency` value.

`$unwind` stage is to break down the `categories` followed by `$match` to keep  the `Currency` `category` embedded array documents.

`$unwind` stage is to break down the `category` followed by `$match` to remove the `Currency` `Value` embedded document.

Final two stages is to `$group` + `$push` the remaining data into embedded array and `$project` the `Currency` value.

You can run one stage at a time to view the intermediate output for better understanding.

```
db.collection.aggregate( 
   { $match : 
       {  $and : 
            [
              { "Level1.Level2.container.categories": 
                 { $elemMatch: 
                   { "category": 
                      { $all: 
                         [ 
                            { $elemMatch : { "Type": "STRING", "Value": "Portfolio" } },
                            { $elemMatch : { "Type": "STRING", "Value": "ABCDEF" } } 
                         ] 
                        } 
                     }
                   }
               }, 
               { "Level1.Level2.container.categories": 
                  { $elemMatch: 
                     { "category":
                         { $elemMatch : { "Type": "STRING", "Value": "Currency" } } 
                      } 
                   }
               }
           ] 
       }
   },
  { $unwind : "$Level1.Level2.container.categories" },
  { $match : { "Level1.Level2.container.categories.category.Value": "Currency" } },
  { $unwind : "$Level1.Level2.container.categories.category" },
  { $match : { "Level1.Level2.container.categories.category.Value": { $ne : "Currency" } } },
  { $group: { _id: null, "Currency": { $push: "$$ROOT" } } }, 
  { $project: { _id: 0, "Currency.Level1.Level2.container.categories.category.Value": 1 } } )
```

Comment: This is giving me all the category except for Portfolio. But you have pointed me in the right direction. I will update the comment shortly.Thanks

Comment: Np. Please add the expected json response and will adjust the query accordingly.

Comment: I have other documents that have additional 'category' fields than 'Portfolio' and 'Currency'. This category sub-structure is dynamic based on the document type.

Comment: also edited my original question, to show another docu type with more categories and expected response

Comment: Thank you for adding all the details. Updated answer.